# OpenCV 2.4.3 release cannot be found to download

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to install the Projector-Camera Calibration software available on: http://mesh.brown.edu/calibration/  . The software demands having installed **Qt 4.8.4** and **OpenCV 2.4.3** on my computer. It cannot work (as far as i know according to my research and *INSTALL.txt* file in the installation package) with any other versions of Qt and OpenCV. My problem is that **OpenCV 2.4.3 version is no longer available anywhere on the Internet to download**. It is not even available on the official OpenCV website: http://opencv.org/releases.html .  I've tried downloading other versions of OpenCV, but none of them seems to work with this calibration software. More specifically, when I try to execute `nmake release` command in my Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017, the

> LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file
>   'opencv_core243.lib'

message is displayed which is expected because other versions of OpenCV do not have *opencv_core243.lib* file. I've done everything demanded in *INSTALL.txt* file, the PATH variable is set properly and everything else.

Can anybody help me with this problem or send me a link for downloading the OpenCV 2.4.3 if it is available somewhere on the Internet?

Comment: Sure it is available: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/2.4.3 However, considering that the release we're talking about is from 2012, then it's quite unlikely you'll find binaries for MSVS 2017, which is significantly younger. You could try to build your own, but since this combination could not have concievably been tested, you're pretty much on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the library should be dependent on that version of OpenCV. From my experience, the camera calibration functions are very stable through different versions.

You should be able to build the library with other versions of OpenCV by editing the file **projector-calib.pro** from:

```
# Windows 7
win32:OPENCV_DIR = "C:/opencv/opencv-2.4.3/opencv/build"
win32:OPENCV_LIB_DIR = $$OPENCV_DIR/x86/vc10/lib
win32:CV_VER = 243
```

to:

```
# Windows 7
win32:OPENCV_DIR = "C:/{YOUR_PATH}/opencv/build"
win32:OPENCV_LIB_DIR = $$OPENCV_DIR/{x64/x86}/vc12/lib
win32:CV_VER = {VERSION}
```

and substituting {YOUR_PATH}, {X64/X86} and {VERSION} properly. For OpenCV 2.4.13, for example, {VERSION} is 2413.